# Inside kubectl plugin, prompt for input?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm writing a `kubectl` plugin to authenticate users, and I would like to prompt the user for a password after the plugin is invoked. From what I understand, it's fairly trivial to get input from STDIN, but I'm struggling seeing messages written to STDOUT. Currently my code looks like this:

In cmd/kubectl-myauth.go:

```golang
// This is mostly boilerplate, but it's needed for the MRE
// https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
package myauth
import (...)
func main() {
    pflag.CommandLine = pflag.NewFlagSet("kubectl-myauth", pflag.ExitOnError)
    root := cmd.NewCmdAuthOp(genericclioptions.IOStreams{In: os.Stdin, Out: os.Stdout, ErrOut: os.Stderr})
    if err := root.Execute(); err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

In pkg/cmd/auth.go:

```golang
package cmd
...
type AuthOpOptions struct {
    configFlags *genericclioptions.ConfigFlags
    resultingContext *api.Context
    rawConfig       api.Config
    args            []string
    ...
    genericclioptions.IOStreams
}
func NewAuthOpOptions(streams genericclioptions.IOStreams) *AuthOpOptions {
    return &AuthOpOptions{
        configFlags: genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(true),
        IOStreams: streams,
    }
}
func NewCmdAuthOp(streams genericclioptions.IOStreams) *cobra.Command {
    o := NewAuthOpOptions(streams)
    cmd := &cobra.Command{
        RunE: func(c *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
            return o.Run()
        },
    }
    return cmd
}
func (o *AuthOpOptions) Run() error {
    pass, err := getPassword(o)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Do Auth Stuff
    // Eventually print an ExecCredential to STDOUT
    return nil
}
func getPassword(o *AuthOpOptions) (string, error) {
    var reader *bufio.Reader
    reader = nil
    pass := ""
    for pass == "" {
        // THIS IS AN IMPORTANT LINE [1]
        fmt.Fprintf(o.IOStreams.Out, "Password with which to authenticate:\n")
        // THE REST OF THIS IS STILL IMPORTANT, BUT LESS SO [2]
        if reader == nil {
            // The first time through, initialize the reader
            reader = bufio.NewReader(o.IOStreams.In)
        }
        pass, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        pass = strings.Trim(pass, "\r\n")
        if pass == "" {
            // ALSO THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT [3]
            fmt.Fprintf(o.IOStreams.Out, `Read password was empty string.
Please input a valid password.
`)
        }
    }
    return pass, nil
}
```

This works the way that I expect when running from outside of the `kubectl` context - namely, it prints the string, prompts for input, and continues. However, from inside the `kubectl` context, I believe the print between the first two all-caps comments ([1] and [2]) is being swallowed by `kubectl` listening on STDOUT. I can get around this by printing to STDERR, but that feels... wrong. Is there a way that I can bypass `kubectl`'s consumption of STDOUT to communicate with the user?

TL;DR: `kubectl` appears to be swallowing all of STDOUT for `kubectl` plugins, but I want to prompt the user for input - is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I'd like to point out that STDERR shouldn't necessarily be considered _wrong_ here. Consider this: You are using a tool in which users may process the output (STDOUT). They may be piping the output to or from scripts. If your prompted information was sent to STDOUT it would not only get swallowed by the script / pipe but possibly cause downstream script issues. When prompted on STDERR it allows the user to see it, enter the required information, and let the command continue in the script / pipe as it would normally without extra information in the stream.

Comment: I'll profess to being ignorant in the field of "which output mechanism to use for user prompts" - STDERR may be correct here. This makes me curious as to why the designers of many command line tools don't, then, provide four output mechanisms - pipe out to users (or one level above), err out to users (or one level above), pipe out to me, and err out to me. This seems far more... dev friendly?  Eh, spare-time PR target.

Comment: @distortedsignal Is Andy's comment satisfactory enough to consider it an answer to your question?

Comment: @OhHiMark - Not really? Andy's answer is a good workaround, but "asking for a password is an error" isn't a great answer (since, in my example, it's in the expected workflow). Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you make the example complete, self-contained so it compiles? It would be much easier to reproduce for people who know Kubernetes but are not fluent in Go.

Comment: @BartoszKP There's a lot left out here because kubectl plugins are large. Check https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-cli-plugin for an example of the structure.

If you want to try this out for yourself, I would recommend making a kubectl plugin in Python and putting in a `print()` call. That should get you _most_ of what I'm trying to get at here.

EDIT: I had the dumb and hit "Enter" prematurely. Sorry about that.

Comment: @distortedsignal Thanks! I've reproduced the problem. I will give it a try.

Comment: @distortedsignal Hm, actually this works for me on GKE. Will try to verify again for OSS K8s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I have no better answer than "Works for me" :-) Here are the steps:

- `git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.git`
- duplicate `sample-cli-plugin` as `test-cli-plugin` (this involves fixing import-restrictions.yaml, rules-godeps.yaml and rules.yaml under staging/publishing - maybe not necessary, but it's safer this way)
- change kubectl-ns.go to kubectl-test.go:

```golang
package main

import (
        "os"

        "github.com/spf13/pflag"

        "k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/genericclioptions"
        "k8s.io/test-cli-plugin/pkg/cmd"
)

func main() {
        flags := pflag.NewFlagSet("kubectl-test", pflag.ExitOnError)
        pflag.CommandLine = flags

        root := cmd.NewCmdTest(genericclioptions.IOStreams{In: os.Stdin, 
                                                           Out: os.Stdout,
                                                           ErrOut: os.Stderr})
        if err := root.Execute(); err != nil {
                os.Exit(1)
        }
}
```

- change ns.go to test.go:

```golang
package cmd

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"

        "github.com/spf13/cobra"

        "k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/genericclioptions"
)

type TestOptions struct {
        configFlags *genericclioptions.ConfigFlags
        genericclioptions.IOStreams
}

func NewTestOptions(streams genericclioptions.IOStreams) *TestOptions {
        return &TestOptions{
                configFlags: genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(true),
                IOStreams:   streams,
        }
}

func NewCmdTest(streams genericclioptions.IOStreams) *cobra.Command {
        o := NewTestOptions(streams)

        cmd := &cobra.Command{
                Use:          "test",
                Short:        "Test plugin",
                SilenceUsage: true,
                RunE: func(c *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
                        o.Run()
                        return nil
                },
        }

        return cmd
}

func (o *TestOptions) Run() error {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Testing Fprintf Stderr\n")
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Testing Fprintf Stdout\n")
        fmt.Printf("Testing Printf\n")
        fmt.Fprintf(o.IOStreams.Out, "Testing Fprintf o.IOStreams.Out\n")
        return nil
}
```

- fix BUILD files accordingly
- build the plugin
- run `make`
- copy `kubectl-test` to /usr/local/bin
- run the compiled `kubectl` binary:

> ~/k8s/_output/bin$ ./kubectl test
>
> Testing Fprintf Stderr
>
> Testing Fprintf Stdout
>
> Testing Printf
>
> Testing Fprintf o.IOStreams.Out

Comment: @distortedsignal Sorry for that - in the first version I needed to verify that this is indeed k8s version, not the GKE version I was trying before. I wanted to remove it from the answer because it's irrelevant, but forgot to remove it from the code.